# Determing Manufacturer/Model number of a paired Bluetooth device on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

Does anyone know of a means to obtain the manufacturer and model number for a bonded Bluetooth device under Android? For example if I'm paired to a Bluetooth headset, I'd like to be able to determine the manufacturer and model of that headset.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Currently there are no public APIs to get this information in Android.
Bluetooth defines a profile called Device ID profile (DID) exactly for this purpose, i.e to exchange the make / model / software-Firmware versions of the device, Android currently does not have APIs that make this available to applications.

As @Jean suggested if you have control on the device - you could code up the remote device name to have this information and extract it as part of the device name when discovered. Some implementations have manufacturer specific AT commands that allow applications to send AT command to the device to extract this information.

Comment: Thanks, Dennis. This is actually for a custom built hardware device. We can control the naming to make this work. But I was hoping for an Android-supported solution. Eh, well. ;-) Thanks for info.

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent of the `Build` class for Bluetooth Devices so the information you can extract from them is quite small. To my knowledge you can only extract a generic name (given by the manufacturer), an address and the UUID.

Such information can be obtain through the [`BluetoothDevice`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html) class. You'll be able to obtain the list of connected devices with the [`getBondedDevices()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getBondedDevices%28%29) method contained in the `BluetoothAdapter` class.

So to my knowledge your best bet would be to extract the name of the Bluetooth Device you're trying to obtain information about and hope the manufacturer gave it a name that contains the information you're looking for. Of course, when it comes to cheap headsets you'll probably be left with gibberish.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Jean-Philippe! That's kind of what I thought I'd end up resorting to...I'm not thrilled about it. But it is what it is. Thanks, again!